# mongolab rest api return null response

Tags: php, curl, mlab

When I execute below code it work fine.

```
    $url = "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/$DB/collections/$COLLECTION?apiKey=$MONGOLAB_API_KEY";
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data),
    )
    );

    echo $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    echo $response_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($response_code == 200)
    {
        $response1=json_decode($response);
        echo("<pre>");print_r($response1);echo("</pre>");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Fail";
        var_dump($data);
        var_dump($status);
    }
```

above work well,it insert one record to mongolab database and return Object id but when execute below code it return null response without any error.
I have check all that thing are right but why response is null.

```
$url = "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/winebook-dev/collections/persons?fo=true&q={'email':'$email'}&apiKey=".MONGOLAB_API_KEY;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if ($status == 200)
{
    $data1 = json_decode($data);
    $len = count($data1);
    if($len > 0 )
    {
        echo "This email already resistered.";
    }
    else
    {
        $url = "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/$DB/collections/$COLLECTION?apiKey=$MONGOLAB_API_KEY";
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)
        )
        );

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $error = curl_error($ch);
        $response_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);

        if ($response_code == 200)
        {
            $response1=json_decode($response);
            echo("<pre>");print_r($response1);echo("</pre>");
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Fail";
            var_dump($data);
            var_dump($status);
        }
    }
}
```

if any one know solution then answer this question suddenly.

thanks in adv.

Comment: Have you tried adding some print/debug statements to determine at what point the code is failing?

Comment: Yes, I have tried adding some print/debug statements but there is not any error.

Comment: When I try only inner curl operation it work fine,but problem is when I put two curl operation. First curl operation work well and second one return only null response not any error. So it is difficult to find where is problem.